# Why isn't BigInteger a primitive

Tags: java, biginteger, primitive

If you use `BigInteger` (or `BigDecimal`) and want to perform arithmetic on them, you have to use the methods `add` or `subtract`, for example. This may sound fine until you realize that this

```
 i += d + p + y;
```

would be written like this for a `BigInteger`:

```
 i = i.add(d.add(p.add(y)));
```

As you can see it is a little easier to read the first line. This could be solved if Java allowed operator overloading but it doesn't, so this begs the question:

Why isn't `BigInteger` a primitive type so it can take advantage of the same operators as other primitive types?

Comment: This question might be better suited to the [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Your question boils down to *why Java doesn't support operator overloading?* which is questioning the current design of Java, which we may or may not know an exact answer.

Comment: Primitives are variables a CPU have support to operate directly, with `BigInteger` this isn't the case. This is a class that supports operation with big (really big if you must) numbers, and such operations require considerable more management. Because its a class and because Java doesn't support operator overloading, you are required to use its methods instead of the simple arithmetic operators you use with primitives.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Java could support BigInteger as a primitive type even without operator overloading. The question is why doesn't support it as a primitive type.

Comment: @Tarik I think the question is why would they bother give this one class special treatment?

Comment: @Tarik it cannot be supported as a primitive because it's not a primitive. `BigInteger` uses a `final int[] mag` to store the data of the number and other stuff to support the, uhm, big integer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's because `BigInteger` is not, in fact, anything that is close to being a primitive. It is implemented using an array and some additional fields, and the various operations include complex operations. For example, here is the implementation of `add`:

```
public BigInteger add(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.signum == 0)
        return this;
    if (signum == 0)
        return val;
    if (val.signum == signum)
        return new BigInteger(add(mag, val.mag), signum);

    int cmp = compareMagnitude(val);
    if (cmp == 0)
        return ZERO;
    int[] resultMag = (cmp > 0 ? subtract(mag, val.mag)
                       : subtract(val.mag, mag));
    resultMag = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(resultMag);

    return new BigInteger(resultMag, cmp == signum ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Primitives in Java are types that are usually implemented directly by the CPU of the host machine. For example, every modern computer has a machine-language instruction for integer addition. Therefore it can also have very simple byte code in the JVM.

A complex type like `BigInteger` cannot usually be handled that way, and it cannot be translated into simple byte code. It cannot be a primitive.

---

So your question might be "Why no operator overloading in Java". Well, that's part of the language philosophy.

---

And why not make an exception, like for `String`? Because it's not just one operator that is the exception. You need to make an exception for the operators `*`, `/`, `+`,`-`, `<<`, `^` and so on. And you'll still have some operations in the object itself (like `pow` which is not represented by an operator in Java), which for primitives are handled by speciality classes (like `Math`).

Comment: Great point about bytecode. Worth noting that in other languages (like JavaScript), Strings are considered primitive - the concept of "primitive" is fairly shaky, and to some extent language-dependent.

Comment: Although requiring support in various libraries, it is still feasible to BigInteger as a primitive type. I do not see any technical obstacle in doing that. Even the lack of CPU support is not an argument: You must remember the early CPUs where floating point operations were emulated while still supported by languages such as C.

Comment: "keep in mind that String already has a special place in the Java Language Specification" What is to prevent having the same special place for BigInteger or any other type such as Complex numbers for that matter?

Comment: @Tarik, everything is possible - I remember seeing machine language instructions in VAX/11 for things like function calls (a single machine instruction that creates a stack frame and moves the instruction pointer). I believe this would make JVM design and verification rather more complex. They picked a reasonable cutoff point there, IMO. It's also worth noting that Oracle intends to do away with the concept of primitives by Java 10.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, because the informal meaning of "primitive" is that it's data that can be handled directly with a single [CPU instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set). In other words, they are primitives because they fit in a 32 or 64 bits word, which is the data architecture that your CPU works with, so they can explicitely be stored in the [registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register).

And thus your CPU can make the following operation:

```
ADD REGISTER_3 REGISTER_2 REGISTER_1     ;;; REGISTER_3 = REGISTER_1 + REGISTER_2
```

A BigInteger which can occupy an arbitrarily large amount of memory can't be stored in a single REGISTER and will need to perform multiple instructions to make a simple sum.

This is why they *couldn't possibly be* a primitive type, and now they actually are objects with methods and fields, a much more complex structure than simple primitive types.

Note: The reason why I called this *informal* is because ultimately the Java designers could define a "Java primitive type" as anything they wanted, they own the word, however this is vaguely the agreed use of the word.

Comment: CPU support is not a prerequisite to have BigInteger as a primitive type in any programming language.

Comment: primitive is a subjective word that anyone can use as they want. What I told is the common agreement. Yes someone could make a primitive type not supported by CPU. The Java designers didn't, they only call primitives to CPU-supported types, as I told you Strings aren't *techinally primitives* (quote from docs) because of this reason. In other languages they can redefine the word as they want, not the point of this Java question.

Answer (score 2):

`int` and `boolean` and `char` aren't primitives so that you can take advantage of operators like `+` and `/`. They are primitives for historical reasons, the biggest of which is performance.

In Java, primitives are defined as just those things that are not full-fledged Objects. Why create these unusual structures (and then re-implement them as proper objects, like `Integer`, later on)? Primarily for performance: operations on Objects were (and are) slower than operations on primitive types. (As other answers mention, hardware support made these operations faster, but I'd disagree that hardware support is an "essential property" of primitives.)

So some types received "special treatment" (and were implemented as primitives), and others didn't. Think of it this way: if even the wildly-popular `String` is not a primitive type, why would `BigInteger` be?

Comment: String is treated as a primitive type in Java.

Comment: @Tarik No, it's [not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) treated as a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

It's because primitive types have a size limit. For instance int is 32 bits and long is 64 bits. So if you create a variable of type int the JVM allocates 32 bits of memory on the stack for it. But as for BigInteger, it "theoretically" has no size limit. Meaning it can grow arbitrarily in size. Because of this, there is no way to know its size and allocate a fixed block of memory on the stack for it. Therefore it is allocated on the heap where the JVM can always increase the size if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types are normally historic types defined by processor architecture. Which is why byte is 8-bit, short is 16-bit, int is 32-bit and long is 64-bit. Maybe when there's more 128-bit architectures, an extra primitive will be created...but I can't see there being enough drive for this...

Comment: CPU support is not a prerequisite to have BigInteger as a primitive type. String is here to prove that.

Comment: you're right, I think i've answered a subtly different question to what has been asked, namely "why isn't there a longer primitive" from a historical pov rather than the specific "why isn't BigInteger a primitive"

Comment: @Tarik Strings are not a primitive type, they just have special treatment. source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @DSquare I will conceed that. Yet, there is no reason why a language would not support any type as a primitive type. The CPU support not being a valid argument.